# Exception when reading output of process

Tags: c++, command-line, process, c++-cli, clr

my problem is the following:

I have a UI created in Visual Studio with C++/CLI.
Now I have a button event that creates a process which runs a C++ Console Application with Parameters.

This works fine, the console application gets executed with parameters with no errors and im also seeing the console window with the right output.

But I still get an exception:

> StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.

I think this has something to do with the Streamreader and some DataReceivedEvents but I have no clue.

This is my code:

```
try {

        String^ parameters = tbLoadXML->Text + " " + tbNumberAnts->Text + " " + tbIteration->Text + " " + tbReduction->Text + " " + tbPheromoneDeposit->Text + " " + tbPheromoneReduction->Text + " " + tbAlpha->Text + " " + tbBeta->Text + " " + reduce.ToString() + " " + algorithm.ToString() + " " + probabilityalgorithm.ToString() + " " + numbercities.ToString();

        Process^ process = gcnew Process();
        process->StartInfo->UseShellExecute = false;
        process->StartInfo->CreateNoWindow = true;      
        process->StartInfo->RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process->Start("TSPACO.exe", parameters);

        StreamReader^ reader = process->StandardOutput;
        String^ output = reader->ReadToEnd();       

        textBox1->Text += output;

        process->WaitForExit();
        process->Close();
    }
    catch (Exception^ ex) {
        MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
    }
```

I also tried a while-loop:

```
while (!process->StandardOutput->EndOfStream)
{
            textBox1->Text += process->StandardOutput->ReadLine();
}
```

But nothing really works - I have no idea why.

Comment: You don't check if the process has actually been started. Relative file paths are often problematic. Try to pass the absolute path to the process as the first argument of `Process::Start()` method.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a solution for my problem - I have no clue why this works but I think the trick is to create a ProcessStartInfo-Object with all the needed properties and then just use the default method of Process::Start without any parameters:

```
    ProcessStartInfo^ startInfo = gcnew ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo->FileName = "TSPACO.exe";
    startInfo->Arguments = parameters;
    startInfo->UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo->CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo->RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    Process^ process = gcnew Process();
    process->StartInfo = startInfo;
    process->Start();

    StreamReader^ reader = process->StandardOutput;
    String^ output = reader->ReadToEnd();

    textBox1->Text += output;

    process->WaitForExit();
    process->Close();
```